# Setup SoapUI to DocuSign rest service

Tags: soapui, docusignapi

How do you setup soapui to call https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/login_information?

Comment: You may Google and find it out easily. This is the article I used to get me started: https://www.soapui.org/rest-testing/getting-started.html

Comment: I have already done that. I am also sending the IntegratorKey, Username and the Password but the response i get back is:

{
   "errorCode": "PARTNER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED",
   "message": "The specified Integrator Key was not found or is disabled. An Integrator key was not specified."
}

Comment: Maybe your keys are not getting posted. Have you seen the "Raw" tab (left of your window. See this image: https://www.soapui.org/soapui/media/images/stories/rest/getting-started/add_rest_request_to_test_case_os.png) in the Request window. Do you see your variables getting posted?

Comment: I might have figured out part of it.

If i use something like this in my browser:
https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&scope=signature&client_id={clientId}&redirect_uri=https://example.com/auth/callback

I get a token back and it looks like it would grant my browser permissions. I just have to figure how to use it in soap UI when choosing  the OAuth 2.0 authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find the below snapshot to configure SOAP UI,

Header will be `X-DocuSign-Authentication`
Value will be `{"Username":"{{username}}","Password":"{{password}}","IntegratorKey":"{{integratorKey}}"}`

[image]